# dll of startup project missing

Tags: asp.net, build

I have a solution file which has around 9 projects.

[image]

VaxanicSite is the Startup project. When I run this project, it gives error Could not load type 'VaxanicSite.Global'. in global.asax file

[image]

If I download the Startup projects' dll file from ftp and place it in bin, it works fine and does not give error. But this does not take my code changes. For them to implement, I do a rebuild solution but that corrups the dll like this :

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @spajce Thanks for putting the images, any idea whats going wrong in the project?

Comment: I guess you have to download that dll manually and then add to your main project.

Comment: Yes did that, it works fine, but if I change the code, rebuild the solution, the dll gets corrupted